# 32601: method not found

Tags: java, http, server, client

An issue I'm having is that I package up a Movie and send it to the server. The server doesn't like it and there int a way to debug that server. I take that same string and unpackage it and it likes the movie but the server doesn't

on the add method, the request is:

Received request:

```
{"method":"add","id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":"{\"Runtime\":\"120 min\",\"Released\":\"12 Dec 2015\",\"Rated\":\"PG\",\"Plot\":\"Dummy Plot\",\"FileName\":\"temp.mpg\",\"Title\":\"james\",\"Actors\":[\"Jane Doe\",\"Joe Smith\"],\"Genre\":[\"family\",\"Animation\"]}"}
Sending back response: HTTP/1.0 400
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length:85
```

but it says:

```
{"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"{\"code\":-32601,\"message\":\"Method Not Found\"}"}
```

to send a "request" from the client to the server there are 2 commands:

```
public abstract Object sendRequest(String string) throws JsonRpcException;
public synchronized Object callRPCMethod(String string, Object[] os) throws JsonRpcException
```

For all my requests I'm using `sendRequest`.

add method is defined here

```
public interface MovieCollection {
   public boolean saveToJsonFile() throws JsonRpcException;
   public boolean resetFromJsonFile() throws JsonRpcException;
   public boolean add(Movie aMovie) throws JsonRpcException;
   public boolean remove(String aName) throws JsonRpcException;
   public Movie get(String aName) throws JsonRpcException;
   public String[] getTitles() throws JsonRpcException;
}

public String packageCall(String operation, Movie movie) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("jsonrpc", "2.0");
    jsonObj.put("method", operation);

    JSONObject object = movie.toJSONObject();
    String temp = object.toString();
    jsonObj.put("params", temp);
    jsonObj.put("id", ++id);

    String string = (String) object2.get("params");

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: `"method":"add"` was not found.  Where is it defined ?

Comment: I answered your question up top. I pasted where the add method is defined.

Comment: This is an interface definition, where is it implemented ?

Comment: Are you using `JSONObject` or `json-rpc` ? looks like you're mixing the two. Examples of how to work with json-rpc can be found in the [*docs*](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/json-rpc-2.0-base.html)

Comment: public boolean add(Movie aMovie) throws JsonRpcException {
        boolean ret = true;
        debug("adding movie named: " + ((aMovie == null) ? "unknown" : aMovie.title));
        try {
            movies.put(aMovie.title, aMovie);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ret = false;
        }
        return ret;
    }

Comment: that is where its implemented

Comment: Awesome. Now what about the other question ?

Comment: sorry, I'm using json-rpc

Comment: So you shouldn't mix it with `JSONObject`. I provided a link to the docs in one of the comments above, it has code examples of both the client side and server side. The client side should use `Map<String, Object>` not `JSONObject`. Go over it and modify your code to work like the examples suggest.

Comment: ok thank you for your help, I will try it and will let you know what the result was